# ATOM : setup blender python environment in my IDE

Tags: python

Anyone using atom here for developing blender addon etc ? How can i setup the blender environment (autocomplete, lib access etc) in Atom ? Tried to googling it but can't found any help. Some tutorial i found is for pycharm, can't find for atom.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to write your own atom package using blender's python lib...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need to make sure, that Atom knows how to lint and autocomplete python-code (there should be plenty of packages to achieve that).

Test your auto-completion and package access with common packages (e.g. `os`). Make sure it works as desired.

If so, the only thing left to do is to get Blender into your python environment. You can either

1. compile Blender as a python package yourself and add it to the `site-packages` folder of your python installation
2. or use `pip` to install the `bpy` package, that should add Blender as a precompiled module (I don't know, how well it's been maintained though).